# How to copy a range of cell but one at a time and always in the last row?

Tags: vba, excel

My first time in this site. I have one Sheet I enter data and at the the end at the click of a Command button I transfer data form that sheet to two other sheets one of them is working find because it is going to a cell then offset the other data points.

The other one it copies to the next cell available but if in the range there is more than one it goes over it instead of going to the next one. So please look at Adddata2 and tell me what am I doing wrong, if I have only one data entry it works but if I have more than one it goes deletes the first one that was added and put the new one and if there is an empty cell it does the same thing. SortCmt are the ones I am looking for!

Thanks

```
Private Sub cmdAjouter5S_Click()
On Error GoTo ERAJOUT
Dim AddDATA As Range


Dim AddDATA2 As Range
Dim MSG, STYLE, TITLE, RESPONSE
Dim Éliminer, Ranger, Nettoyer, Standard, Respect As Variant
Dim SortCmt1, SortCmt2, SortCmt3, SortCmt4, SortCmt5 As String
Dim SetCmt1, SetCmt2, SetCmt3, SetCmt4, SetCmt5 As String
Dim ShineCmt1, ShineCmt2, ShineCmt3, ShineCmt4, ShineCmt5 As String
Dim StandCmt1, StandCmt2, StandCmt3, StandCmt4, StandCmt5 As String
Dim SusCmt1, SusCmt2, SusCmt3, SusCmt4, SusCmt5 As String
Dim AddDate As Date
Dim OPCL As String
Dim RNG As Range

'Définition des variables afin de prendre et d'envoyer les donnée au bon endroit
Set AddDATA = Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 22).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Set AddDATA2 = Sheet63.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
Set RNG = Sheet63.Range("B2:B500")
SortCmt1 = Range("B27").Value
SortCmt2 = Range("B28").Value
SortCmt3 = Range("B29").Value
SortCmt4 = Range("B30").Value
SortCmt5 = Range("B31").Value

'Définition des variables de données
Éliminer = Range("E9").Value
Ranger = Range("G9").Value
Nettoyer = Range("I9").Value
Standard = Range("K9").Value
Respect = Range("M9").Value
AddDate = Sheet1.DTPicker1.Value
Verificateur = Range("D4").Value
OPCL = "Open"

MSG = "Êtes-vous sûr de vouloir ajouter les données?" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
"Vous ne pourrez les modifiées par la suite, donc assurez-vous que celles-ci sont exactes!"
STYLE = vbYesNo + vbCritical + vbDefaultButton2
TITLE = "IMPORTANT MESSAGE"
RESPONSE = MsgBox(MSG, STYLE, TITLE)

If Range("P9").Value = 0 Or Range("D4").Value = 0 Or Range("P9").Value = "Error" Then GoTo EAJOUT
If RESPONSE = vbYes Then
  AddDATA.Value = AddDate
  AddDATA.Offset(0, 2).Value = Éliminer
  AddDATA.Offset(0, 3).Value = Ranger
  AddDATA.Offset(0, 4).Value = Nettoyer
  AddDATA.Offset(0, 5).Value = Standard
  AddDATA.Offset(0, 6).Value = Respect
  AddDATA.Offset(0, 11).Value = Verificateur
  AddDATA2.Value = SortCmt1
  AddDATA2.Value = SortCmt2
  AddDATA2.Value = SortCmt3
  AddDATA2.Value = SortCmt4
  AddDATA2.Value = SortCmt5

  MsgBox "Vos données ont été ajoutez!" & vbCrLf & "Merci", vbInformation, "Équipe 5S!"

Else
  MsgBox "Vérifiez et recommencez au besoin", vbInformation, "VÉRIFICATION"
  GoTo AJOUT
End If

Range("B27:B31").Value = ""
Range("B42:B46").Value = ""
Range("B57:B61").Value = ""
Range("B72:B76").Value = ""
Range("B87:B91").Value = ""
Range("S20:S24").Value = ""
Range("S35:S39").Value = ""
Range("S50:S54").Value = ""
Range("S65:S69").Value = ""
Range("S80:S84").Value = ""
Range("D4").Value = ""

For Each cell In RNG
  If cell.Value <> "" And IsEmpty(cell.Offset(0, 3).Value) = True Then
    cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = OPCL
  End If
Next

GoTo AJOUT
EAJOUT:
MsgBox "Vous n'avez pas entrées de donnée! Retournez entrer vos données."

AJOUT:
Exit Sub

ERAJOUT:
MsgBox Err.Description
MsgBox "Une erreur c'est produite voir avec Martin SVP"
Resume EAJOUT

End Sub
```

Comment: Your `addDATA` has a bunch of Offsets to get the data to the correct places. Your `addDATA2` does not have any Offsets at all, so it's just overwriting the same cell over and over.

Comment: Yes your right but I thought that the AddData2 would go to the next cell because once the first SortCmt is being added it should find the next empty cell in the same column? the offset is part of the Adddata2

Comment: No, not at all.  You have to explicitly tell it where to put data every time.  It doesn't automatically find new cells

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because with:

```
AddDATA2.Value = SortCmt1
AddDATA2.Value = SortCmt2
AddDATA2.Value = SortCmt3
AddDATA2.Value = SortCmt4
AddDATA2.Value = SortCmt5
```

your overwriting 5 times the value of cell AddDATA2

While if you want to write Sheet63.Range("B27:B31") values down a column starting from AddDATA2 cell then you'd write:

```
AddDATA2.Resize(5).Value = Sheet63.Range("B27:B31").Value
```

Or, if you want thise values copied along a row from AddDATA2 rightwards:

```
AddDATA2.Resize(,5).Value = Application.Transpose(Sheet63.Range("B27:B31").Value)
```

Comment: Sorry my data comes from Sheet2 and not from Sheet63 I have tried your code with resize and it did not work for some reason. Myabe it's me who wasn't clear. Sheet2 B27:B31 has values in them or are empty I need if it has value to go on Sheet 63 Column B

Comment: Just change Sheet63 to Sheet2